# View not rendering in % includes

Tags: django

Using Django I have a basic view that renders some data from the database.

When I pass the view into my page `{% include 'pages/games_table.html' %}`  the data is not being passed in. But if I go directly to the view I can see the data.

**view.py**

```
@login_required
def showGame(request):
    results=Game.objects.all()
    return render(request,"pages/games_table.html",{"Game":results})
    
    class Meta:
        db_table="apps_game"
```

Direct to view i get this:

[image]

but when i view within my template all i get is a blank table

[image]

games_table

```
 <div class="card-body">
                                    <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered dt-responsive  nowrap w-100">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Position</th>
                                            <th>Office</th>
                                            <th>Age</th>
                                            <th>Start date</th>
                                            <th>Salary</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            {% for results in Game %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{results.project_name}}</td>
                                            <td><a href={{results.project_website}}>{{results.project_website}}</a></td>
                                            <td><a href={{results.project_type}}>{{results.project_type}}</a></td>
                                            <td>{{results.project_positive_count }}</td>
                                            <td>{{results.project_negative_count }}</td>
                                            <td>{{results.project_unrated_count }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
```

I think i have past data correctly so not sure what i am missing?

Ignore the table headings/data this is just me using dummy data

Thanks

Comment: It is passed as `Game`, not as `results` to the template.

Comment: Sorry, Willem Im not following. It works if i go direct to games_table.html

Comment: share the `pages/games_table.html` template.

Comment: Are you using the `{% include %}` in a different view/template and you're expecting it to be filled with data from the showGame view? Can you show the view/template for the other view?

Comment: So basically I want to be able to show this view on a number of pages. so I have created a separate view and template games_table.html and then want to render the results in games.html

Comment: @IainShelvington yes i would like to show the data that is generated by `ShowGame` at the moment this is rendered in `games_table` and then im passing `{% include 'pages/games_table.html' %} ` into my template

Answer (score 0):

The tag **include** is doing what is expected, by including only the template, the html without data, the table with data that you show is through a view, which receives the context that has the data.

You could solve by:

- Merge the data in the context of the main view, also merge the table
  in the template of the main view, or,
- Build a JSON view to dynamically show the data in the table.

Comment: Thanks. What is the correct way to do this? Would it be easier to just create a new view just for this template? But this means I need to duplicate views to enable the data to be on each page?

Comment: No, you don't need to duplicate, on the contrary, simplify them, the correct way is what you need, you could make the query in the view, pass it to the template as another data in the context, or, the view you have, convert it to a JSON view, and in the frontend get it with ajax and draw it in your table

Comment: Sounds really simple,